# Plays video by phaser.js on iOS (safari) without fullscreen

Tags: ios, iphone, video, mobile-safari, phaser-framework

How to play 2-3-5 videos by phaser on same time in inline mode (without fullscreen) on iOS?

How to check it?
https://phaser.io/examples/v2/video/change-source

In android / desktop video plays inline and no need click, but on iOS video plays only after click and opens that video in fullscreen

[image: iOS fullscreen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution for native videos play: https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video

And made a solution for phaser based on it:

```
var video = game.add.video('some_video');
...
video.mute = true; // muted videos play inline without user interaction
video.unlock(); //  manual phaser unlock http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.2/Phaser.Video.html#unlock
video.video.setAttribute('playsinline', 'playsinline'); // for inline mode

video.play(true); // play that video with loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I couldn't find the solution.
the native player keeps opening

```
   video = game.add.video ('space');
   video.addToWorld();
   video.unlock();
   video.setAttribute('playsinline');
   video.play(true);
```